# jquery get last object in variable

Tags: jquery

```
var $previous = $('.visible:visible');
```

this contains the visible objects. I want to get the last objects id in this variable. The objects changes. Objects example section1, section2 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:last` selector:

```
var $previous = $('.visible:visible:last').attr('id');
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the .last JQuery function:

```
.last()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `last()` to get the last item in the jQuery object and `attr` to get the `id`

```
var $previous = $('.visible:visible').last().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the attribute for ID:

```
var $previous_id = $('.visible:visible').last().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$previous.last().attr('id');
```